# Beamer/Beamerposter Line spacing in title doesn't seem to work

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I'm trying to increase the linespacing in the title section, and I feel like I've tried a lot of things, but none of them seem to work.  Whenever I use `\fontsize{32}{36}`, the second parameter doesn't seem to do anything (yet the first one, does indeed change the size).

Also, as more of an aside, if anyone also knows how to make the section not be in the centre of the poster, but rather, directly underneath the university, that'd be great.

[image: poster]

This is the `.tex`:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,scale=1.4,size=a1,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{I6pd2}}
\usepackage{microtype}


\listfiles

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Simulating Adiabatic Aperiodic Poling Of A Structure}
\author{Bob}
\institute[Uni]{University}
\date[January 20, 2014]{January 20, 2014}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.9\textwidth}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}

\begin{block}{Introduction}
Simulation of lithium niobate poling investingating adiabatically varying the period and dutycycle of the poling to achieve effective frequency mixing.
\end{block}

\vfill

\begin{block}{Feature Extraction}
abc

\end{block}

\vfill

\begin{block}{Feature Description}
\begin{itemize}
\item Scale Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT)
\begin{itemize}
\item 128-dimensional descriptor, histogram of gradients, scale invariant
\end{itemize}
\item Speeded Up Robust Features (SURF)
\begin{itemize}
\item 64-dimensional descriptor, histogram of gradients, scale invariant
\end{itemize}
\item face recognition: invariance w.r.t. rotation is often not necessary
\begin{itemize}
\item rotation dependent upright-versions U-SIFT, U-SURF-64, U-SURF-128
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}


\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is the `.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthemeI6pd2}  % this style was created by Thomas Deselaers an 

Philippe Dreuw

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{tangocolors}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\mode<presentation>

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{darkTeal}{RGB}{24,75,82}

\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=tabutter,bg=darkTeal}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=tabutter, bg=white}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\large,series=\tt}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=green}
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in headline}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{institute in headline}{fg=black}

\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=ta3orange, bg=ta2gray}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=ta2orange, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=ta2orange, bg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=tachameleon, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=ta3aluminium,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=taorange,bg=ta2gray}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\huge,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\Large}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{fg=ta2orange}

% equal font sizes for all levels
%\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\normalsize}
%\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}
%\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\normalsize}

%\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=ta3gray}

%\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=taorange}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=ta3skyblue}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  % no navigation on a poster

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \vskip1cm
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.0cm,dp=1.0cm,center,leftskip=-1em]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}%
    {\phantom{Gg}\insertblocktitle}% phantom because of baseline problem
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.5ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \vskip0.3cm
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{block end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \leavevmode

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \vskip2cm
    \begin{columns}[T]
      \begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.4\paperwidth}
        \vskip8ex
        \begin{center}
          \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{CudosLogo.pdf}
        \end{center}
        \vskip2ex
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.5\paperwidth}
        \vskip4ex
        \raggedleft
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\centering\textbf{{\fontsize{100pt}{50}\selectfont{\inserttitle\\[1ex]}}}}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \vspace{2cm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{30pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{text under separation line}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}}
    \vspace{0.5cm} \\
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertinstitute}}   
    \end{center}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{5pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \leavevmode
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{author in head/foot}
    \begin{center}
          \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{UniLogos.pdf}
    \end{center}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Display a grid to help align images ... and it looks nice with this color scheme
%\beamertemplategridbackground[1cm]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mode<all>
```

Comment: Couldn't compile your code because a `tangocolors` package, required by the `I6pd2` theme, is missing from my local TeX distro. As for your second question, try adding option `[t]` to the frame, as in `\begin{frame}[t]`.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for taking a look.  I was going to upload tangocolors.sty, but realised it was here: http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/recursiveengines/products/BRIMS2010/poster/tangocolors.sty

Comment: Voted to close this as unclear: I cannot reproduce the problem with a simple example. Please edit your example down to some minimal code that shows the problem. Then it will be much easier for us to see what is going on and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the title inside a `minipage`

```
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries,size=\fontsize{100}{50}}

\begin{minipage}[b][0mm][t]{.45\paperwidth}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in headline}{%        
        \usebeamerfont{title}{%
            \normalbaselines%
            \inserttitle\par%               
        }%
    }%
\end{minipage}%
```